# Python chart axis formatting doesn't work for subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time, formatter

I have a pandas dataframe with an index of `datetime.time` objects derived from a DatetimeIndex,

```
In: df.index
Out: 
Index([00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00, 01:30:00, 02:00:00, 02:30:00, 03:00:00,
       03:30:00, 04:00:00, 04:30:00, 05:00:00, 05:30:00, 06:00:00, 06:30:00,
       07:00:00, 07:30:00, 08:00:00, 08:30:00, 09:00:00, 09:30:00, 10:00:00,
       10:30:00, 11:00:00, 11:30:00, 12:00:00, 12:30:00, 13:00:00, 13:30:00,
       14:00:00, 14:30:00, 15:00:00, 15:30:00, 16:00:00, 16:30:00, 17:00:00,
       17:30:00, 18:00:00, 18:30:00, 19:00:00, 19:30:00, 20:00:00, 20:30:00,
       21:00:00, 21:30:00, 22:00:00, 22:30:00, 23:00:00, 23:30:00],
      dtype='object')
```

I am plotting a chart from the df:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplot
ax.plot(df.index, df,  marker='', linestyle='solid',linewidth=1, alpha=1)
```

I want to format the x-axis to have ticks labesls every 4 hours

Using `matplotlib.dates`

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=4))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H'))
```

has no effect as the index is not a `DatetimeIndex`, so what do I use to format the axis?

Comment: I guess the answer is simply: Use datetime objects as index or at least use datetime object as x values for plotting.

Comment: OK, how to convert from `datetime.time` objects to `datetime` without adding spurious data information?

Comment: Just take the 1st of january 1900 or whatever date you like.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ImportanceofBeingErnest the answer is to change the `datetime.time` objects in the index back to 'datetime'objects to restore the `DatetimeIndex`:

```
import datetime as dt   
random_date = dt.date(1901, 1, 1)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex([dt.datetime.combine(random_date, t) for t in df.index])
```